# Laravel move url downloaded file to storage clean solution

Tags: laravel-8

## Problem statement

- I am using `Laravel Framework 8.83.23`
- being given an url, a file **A** gets downloaded using **wget** to a file system

A brief example just to get an idea:

```
$cmd = sprintf(
            '"%s" --no-check-certificate "%s" -O "%s" 2>&1',
            $wgetPath,
            $url,
            $filePath
        );
        $ret = exec($cmd, $output, $result_code);
```

- the wget is executed using **exec()** on a linux file system
- file **A** then needs to be moved to a Storage, let's call it `Storage::disk('posters')`
- I want the `Storage` facade to handle the file, because, for example, if **wget** would download the file directly to the storage path using known file system path string, the `Storage` facade would not be triggered - you no longer can use `Storage::fake('posters')` in tests, because the file would get downloaded to the same directory, not the fake one

### Proposed solution idea

- I create a new disk, called `Storage::disk('temp')`
- the wget will download the file to that directory (disc) using string path. The `Storage` facade will not trigger using code like `storage_path(sprintf("app{$DS}temp{$DS}%s.%s", $fname, $extension));` where `$DS` is directory separator
- then, move the file from `Storage::disk('temp')` to `Storage::disk('posters')`
- working code

```
Storage::disk('posters')->put(
              $fName . '.jpg',
                Storage::disk('temp')->get($fName . '.jpg')
            );
```

- the code above will use the Storage facade, and therefore, `Storage::fake('posters')` can be used in tests

### Question

- is there a cleaner solution you would propose? Creating a new storage disc for temporary files directory does not seem clean to me
- I am not sure, whether there is some temporary storage already available for me to use?

Comment: Just to know, why don't you directly download it in to `posters`?

Comment: Because when downloading directly to `posters`, using path such as `storage_path(sprintf("app{$DS}posters{$DS}%s.%s", $fname, $extension));`, it does download it to `app/posters`, but when the code runs as a part of a test, where Storage is faked, the file still gets downloaded to `app/posters`, not to the mocked fake storage